# scala having a case statement inside a lambda

Tags: list, scala, collections

How come you cannot have a case statement inside of a lambda function?  My code looks something like

```
def f(list:List[String]):List[Int] = list.map( _ match{ case _.length > 1 => _.length else 1})

input 
"mike" 
"tom"
"t"
" "

output
4  
3
1
1
```

As you can see, I am trying to do a case inside the lambda. I have tried so many ways with the syntax.

Comment: What are your 3 wildcards (`_`) supposed to be? The same parameter? 3 different parameters? Why are you using `match` instead of `if` if you only have two possibilities, and you're not matching any patterns?

Comment: Maybe if you could write the code you want in a full function, it will be clearer what you want your lambda to do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You seem to be trying to use a *guard clause* and you may wish to look at [a tutorial on match statements](https://newcircle.com/s/post/1696/an_Introduction_to_pattern_matching_in_scala_brian_clapper_tutorial).

However, what you're doing doesn't require a match statement at all.

```
list.map(x => math.max(1, x.length))
```

Or, if `max` didn't exist and we didn't want to call `x.length` twice, we could assign a variable:

```
list.map{ x =>
  val len = x.length
  if (len > 1) len else 1
}
```

Or, we can use a match statement, either with a guard clause or bare:

```
list.map(_.length match { case x if x > 1 => x; case _ => 1 })
list.map(_.length match { case x => if (x > 1) x else 1 })
```

Note that `_` is *not a variable*.  You cannot use it repeatedly.  It means, alternately, "ignore this", "make this a function", "put in whatever the next variable is".  If you want a variable that you can refer to repeatedly, you have to name it (e.g. `x`).

Note also that `else` is *not* an "if not" alternative to `case` statements.  If you want a default catch-whatever-remains statement (and you should!), use `case _ =>`.